# vb.net Passing a list through a function without list value changed

Tags: vb.net, list, function, arguments

The list value changeed here when passed ByVal why
,it must be not changed.

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        Dim value As Integer = 1
        Dim value2 As New List(Of Decimal)
        value2.Add(1)
        value2.Add(2)

        ' The integer value doesn't change here when passed ByVal.
        Example1(value)
        Console.WriteLine(value)

        ' The list value changeed here when passed ByVal.
        Example3(value2)
        Console.WriteLine(value)
```

End Sub

```
    Sub Example1(ByVal test As Integer)
        test = 10
    End Sub

    Sub Example3(ByVal test As List(Of Decimal))
        test.Add(3)
    End Sub
```

its solved ,the solution is making new copy:

```
Sub Example3(ByVal test As List(Of Decimal))
        Dim testnew As New List(Of Decimal)
        testnew.AddRange(test)
        testnew.Add(3)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do some reading on value types and reference types and passing method arguments by value and by reference.  They are related but not the same thing.  When you pass a method argument by value, you create a copy of the variable being passed.  If the variable is a value type, i.e. a structure, then that means creating a copy of the value.  If the variable is a reference type, i.e. a class, then that means creating a copy of the reference.  The thing is, the original reference and the copy still both refer to the same object.

The reason that reference types exist is that you wouldn't want to create copies of large objects every time you assigned them somewhere.  In the case of passing a collection to a method, it's almost always the case that any change you make inside the method you will want to be reflected outside.  In the rare case that you don't, it's up to you to create a copy of the collection first and pass that in.

When you pass a value type by value, you create a copy of the value.  That means that no changes you make inside the method can affect the original variable.  You can assign a new value to the parameter or you can set a property of the value and the change will not be reflected outside the method.  Of course, value types should generally be immutable and so setting a property should not be possible, but there are times that that "rule" gets broken.

When you pass a reference type by value, you create a copy of the reference.  That means that assigning a different object to the parameter inside the method will not affect the original variable.  There is still only one object though, referred to by the original variable and the parameter. As such, if you set a property of that object via the parameter then that change will be reflected in the original variable, because it's the same object.

When you pass a value type by reference, you create a new reference to the value.  That means that any changes you make inside the method will affect the original variable.  You can assign a new value to the parameter or you can set a property of the value and the change will be reflected outside the method.

When you pass a reference type by reference, you create a new reference to the original reference.  That means that assigning a different object to the parameter inside the method will affect the original variable.  There's still just one object, so setting a property on the parameter will still affect the original variable too.

Those are the only four possibilities: value type by value, reference type by value, value type by reference and reference type by reference.  In none of those scenarios is a copy of a reference type object made so in none of those scenarios can you set a property of a reference type object via a method parameter and have that change not be reflected in the original variable.

If you want a copy of the original object then it's up to you to create one explicitly.  Whether you do that inside the method or outside really depends on the specific circumstances.  That means that you need to change your code to this:

```
Sub Example3(ByVal test As List(Of Decimal))
    Dim copy = test.ToList()

    copy.Add(3)
End Sub
```

or this:

```
Dim copy = value2.ToList()

Example3(copy)
```

Let me just repeat the important point here: there is NO WAY to pass a reference type object to a method, modify the object via the parameter inside the method and have that not affect the original variable (assigning a different object to the parameter is NOT modifying the object).  If you want a modification inside the method to not affect the original variable then you need a copy of the object and the ONLY way that will happen is if YOU do it explicitly.

Comment: thank you for your answer,i know all this,but if the argument are list(of...) its values changed same i use it byref or byvalue

Comment: I'm not sure you do know all this if you're still asking that question.  I'll add some more information to my answer.

Comment: You should take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: thanks for your answer ,its solved,by making copy